# opencv- how to draw lines for feature match within the same image

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

Is it possible to draw lines similar to the lines in the pic using `cv2.drawMatches()`? I have used `SLIC superpixel segmentation` and passed each segmentation to `ORB` to obtain key points and descriptors, sorted them and now trying to plot them in a single image.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: click "enter image description here" for the image,i am using cv2.drawMatches(image,key[0],image,key[1],sorted_match[0],None, flags=2) ,if i iterate over the segments the output gets overridden

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and add the code, or in general what you have tried so far, into the question instead of into a comment.

Comment: You have the keypoints (which contain the x,y coordinates) and the matches. Just draw a line (`cv::line`) for each match.

Comment: code http://answers.opencv.org/question/210650/how-to-draw-lines-for-feature-match-within-the-same-image/